# Get the last value if null on given datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am working on a SQL query where I have 2 tables:

```
TagTable (TagID int,PlcTagName nvarchar(50),HMINameDescription nvarchar(50))
AlarmHistory ([AlarmID] [int] , [DateAndTime] [datetime],[TagID] [smallint], 
[ValueBool] [bit] ,  
[ValueNumeric] [decimal](18, 2) ,[RepType] [nvarchar](50) , [IsActive] [bit] )
```

TagTable Column 'TagID' is foreign key in AlarmHistory table.

Here I want to fetch record from AlarmHistory whose tagid in TagTable has HmiNamedescription is 'TEMP_ZONE_1'and 'Z1_TEMP_SP'. I used following query

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP1

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, DATEANDTIME) DATEANDTIME,max([TEMP_ZONE_1])[TEMP_ZONE_1],max([Z1_TEMP_SP])[Z1_TEMP_SP]     
        INTO #TEMP1 FROM 
        (
            SELECT convert(varchar(16),DATEANDTIME,121) DATEANDTIME, ISNULL([TEMP_ZONE_1],0)[TEMP_ZONE_1],ISNULL([Z1_TEMP_SP],0)[Z1_TEMP_SP]
        
            FROM
            (
                SELECT A.DATEANDTIME, T.HMINameDescription TAGDESCRIPTION, ISNULL(A.VALUENUMERIC,0) VALUENUMERIC FROM ALARMHISTORY A WITH (NOLOCK) JOIN TAGTABLE T WITH (NOLOCK) ON 
                T.TAGID=A.TAGID WHERE A.repType='T' and CONVERT(DATE,A.DATEANDTIME,103)>=CONVERT(DATE,@DTFRM,103) AND CONVERT(DATE,A.DATEANDTIME,103)<=CONVERT(DATE,@DTTO,103)                      
                
            )Z
            PIVOT
            (
                MAX(VALUENUMERIC) FOR TAGDESCRIPTION IN([TEMP_ZONE_1],[Z1_TEMP_SP])
            )P 
        )Y Group by DATEANDTIME 
        
        SELECT * FROM #TEMP1 ORDER BY DATEANDTIME
```

The entry in TagTable

```
TagID   PLCTagName                     HMINameDescription
  
 234    Zone[1].Temp                   TEMP_ZONE_1
 235    Zone[2].Temp                   TEMP_ZONE_2
 236    Zone[3].Temp                   TEMP_ZONE_3
 308    Zone[1].Temp_Sp                Z1_TEMP_SP
 309    Zone[2].Temp_Sp                Z2_TEMP_SP
 310    Zone[3].Temp_Sp                Z3_TEMP_SP
 311    Blower[1].PV                   FURNACEPRESSURE1
 313    Furnance_Pressure_SP[1]        FP1_SETPOINT
 321    Blower[2].PV                   FURNACEPRESSURE2
 323    Furnance_Pressure_SP[2]        FP2_SETPOINT
```

And entry in Alarm Table is

```
AlarmID  DateAndTime               TagID  ValueBool ValueNumeric  RepType   IsActive

430866   2020-06-30 05:03:08.000    234    NULL     182.78        T         0
430867   2020-06-30 05:04:16.000    308    NULL     1500.00       T         0
430867   2020-06-30 05:04:16.000    234    NULL     182.89        T         0
430868   2020-06-30 05:05:40.000    234    NULL     182.89        T         0
430866   2020-06-30 05:06:21.000    234    NULL     183.12        T         0
430867   2020-06-30 05:07:19.000    234    NULL     183.24        T         0
430868   2020-06-30 05:08:56.000    234    NULL     183.35        T         0
```

The Output coming after using the above query is :-

```
DATEANDTIME               TEMP_ZONE_1   Z1_TEMP_SP

2020-06-30 05:03:00.000     182.78       0.00
2020-06-30 05:04:00.000     182.89      1500.00
2020-06-30 05:05:00.000     182.89      0.00
2020-06-30 05:06:00.000     183.12      0.00
2020-06-30 05:07:00.000     183.24      0.00
2020-06-30 05:08:00.000     183.35      0.00
```

There is only one entry of Z1_TEMP_SP in AlarmHistory that's why is not 0 rest of time. But I want its last value until last value changes. The output I want is:

```
DATEANDTIME               TEMP_ZONE_1   Z1_TEMP_SP

2020-06-30 05:03:00.000     182.78       0.00
2020-06-30 05:04:00.000     182.89      1500.00
2020-06-30 05:05:00.000     182.89      1500.00
2020-06-30 05:06:00.000     183.12      1500.00
2020-06-30 05:07:00.000     183.24      1500.00
2020-06-30 05:08:00.000     183.35      1500.00
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Without actual sample data from your table, I can't give a representative answer for your data, however, for the wrong results you are getting you would need to put your data into groups and then get the MAX:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DATEANDTIME,
           TEMP_ZONE_1,
           Z1_TEMP_SP,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN Z1_TEMP_SP != 0 OR Z1_TEMP_SP IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY DATEANDTIME ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT DATEANDTIME,
       TEMP_ZONE_1,
       MAX(Z1_TEMP_SP) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp) AS Z1_TEMP_SP
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: That was actual data @Larnu

Comment: You state *"The Output coming is"* @SunnySandeep, ergo that data isn't the data in your table. Especially considering your table has more than 3 columns.

Comment: it is not giving desired result as it is showing value of Z1_Temp_Sp= 1 but it has value 1500.